# single ticket domestic to international connection at LAX T5/Regional and T4 - disability

Tags: air-travel, transit, lax

I’m travelling alone for the first time, I have a hidden disability that makes communicating with strangers challenging, so I prefer to know all travel details ahead of time.  I have never previously travelled via LAX. I have no mobility issues.

Flights booked on one ticket with BA, operated by AA. My flight itinerary states the Domestic flight arrives LAX T4, but looking at flight checker this flight usually lands at the T5/Regional Terminal gates 52C or 52D. The international flight departs T4. I have three hours between landing and departing.

I’d like to know: 
will I be bused from RT to T4 or will I ‘land’ at T5?
will I need to collect and recheck my baggage? 
is three hours sufficient time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal 4 and 5 or close and it is easily walkable. There are airside connections, but there is a lot of construction happening and it's hard to determine what the current state is. There is an airside tunnel between T4 and T5

Here are some good resources: https://onemileatatime.com/connect-terminals-lax/, https://milestomemories.boardingarea.com/lax-airside-connections-between-terminals/

You should get both boarding passes when you check in for your first flight. In LAX you just have to get off the arriving plane, look up the gate for your departing flight and follow the signage to this gate. 3 hours is plenty for that unless there is a major delay with your first leg.